# How to print key and values in Meteor Template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-helper

I have JSON from helper

```
{
    "Name": "abc",
    "Age": 24,
    "Address" {
        "street" : "xyz street",
        "city" : "zyz city",
        "country" : "XY"
        }
}
```

I want to print the address with key and values

```
<template name="User">
{{#with user}}
 Name : {{Name}}
 Age : {{Age}}
    {{#each Address}}
       {{key}} : {{value}} //Here is my question
    {{/each}}
{{/with}}
</template>
```

How to print key and values in a template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `{{#each}}` block helper only accepts cursors and arrays arguments.

You could override the Address helper to make it return an array instead of an object.

```
Template.User.helpers({
  Address: function(){
    return _.map(this.Address, function(value, key){
      return {
        key: key,
        value: value
      };
    });
  }
});
```

You might want to define this utility function as a template helper :

JS

```
Template.registerHelper("objectToPairs",function(object){
  return _.map(object, function(value, key) {
    return {
      key: key,
      value: value
    };
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="User">
  <ul>
    {{#each objectToPairs Address}}
      <li>{{key}} - {{value}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes to be made in JS

```
var AddressSet=CollectionName.find( {  } );
```

Changes to be made in HTML

```
      {{#each AddressSet}}
        {{#each Address}}
              {{this.street}}
              {{this.city}}
              {{this.country}}
       {{/each}}

       {{/each}}
```

Comment: I want to print key and as well as value. Your code has only values. Anyway thanks.  @saimeunt Understand my question right.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, the keys are supposed to be unknown.